# Global variable not setting correctly when starting neovim

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, variables

I'm trying to setup separate configs for my WSL, Windows, and MSYS2 environments in the same `init.vim` with simple if-else statements. So, I'll need to know what environment I'm in. To know that I decided to declare a global variable in the following manner.

```
if !exists("g:env")
    if system('uname') =~ "msys"        " uname returns MSYS_NT-10.0-19041
        let g:env = "MSYS2"
    elseif has('windows')
        let g:env = "WIN"
    else
        let g:env = "LINUX"
    endif
endif
```

But when I start neovim from inside MSYS2, this block sets `g:env` equal to "WIN" for some reason.

Now, if I source the block (inside the `if !exists` block, obviously) after neovim has already booted up, then `g:env` is set to "MSYS2". So, maybe there is something going on at the startup?

---

```
NVIM v0.5.0
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 -DNVIM_TS_HAS_SET_MATCH_LIMIT /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG /W3 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -DWIN32 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/config -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/src -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/nvim-deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/src/nvim/auto -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/include
Compiled by runneradmin@fv-az152-786

Features: -acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM\sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "C:/Program Files/nvim/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `=~` will either ignore case or not depending on whether the `'ignorecase'` option is set. You're trying to match a lowercase pattern, but the text you're matching contains an uppercase instance of the pattern. The `'ignorecase'` option defaults to off, but is commonly set in one's `init.vim`, so I believe that's why you're getting different behavior during startup and after NeoVim is already running.

You can easily fix this by using the `=~?` operator instead, which will *always* ignore case, independent of whether the `'ignorecase'` option is set or not.

```
if system('uname') =~? "msys"
```

Comment: Oh, right. Forgot about that.